# jinja2 flask: using rowspan twice while iterating

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm passing the following lists to a Jinja2 template via flask:

```
yrs = [2016, 2017]
months = [['June'], ['January', 'February']]
names = [[['John', 'Mike']], [['Sara'], ['Steph', 'James']]]
```

I'm trying to make a table that looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/46qqfef5/4/

Here is the unsuccessful Jinja2 code I've put together to make that happen:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for yr_index in range(yrs | count) %}
        {% for month_index in range(months[yr_index] | count) %}
          {% for name_index in range(names[yr_index][month_index] | count) %}
            <tr>
              {% if loop.first %}
                {% if loop.first %}
                  <td rowspan="{{ names[yr_index] | count }}">{{ yrs[yrs_index] }}</td>
                {% endif %}
              <td rowspan="{{ names[yr_index][month_index] | count }}">{{ months[yr_index][month_index] }}</td>
              {% endif %}
              <td>{{ names[yr_index][month_index][name_index] }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
<div>
```

So I'm basically just trying to unpack these lists into an organized table but I'm having a lot of trouble with the `rowspan` attribute. Any tips would be much appreciated, even if it has to do with changing the structure of the python lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this first (didn't test). It seems you misused the `loop.first` (you have nested loops, you can't depend on the `loop.first` actually). And you also need to flatten the `names[yr_index]` list before retrieving the count.

Consider reading this: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/#accessing-the-parent-loop.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for yr in yrs %}
        {% set yr_loop = loop %}
        {% for month in months[loop.index0] %}
          {% set month_loop = loop %}
          {% for name in names[yr_loop.index0][loop.index0] %}
            <tr>
              {% if loop.first %}
                {% if month_loop.first %}
                  <td rowspan="{{ names[yr_loop.index0]|sum(start=[])|count }}">{{ yr }}</td>
                {% endif %}
                <td rowspan="{{ loop.length }}">{{ month }}</td>
              {% endif %}
              <td>{{ name }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
<div>
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "UndefinedError: 'list object' has no attribute 'values'". Looks like I need to figure out how to count the items per year. Great tip on accessing the parent loop - that should work!

Comment: @jcmetz21 Just remove the `.values()`. My mistake.

Comment: The new url for this is now [this](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/tricks/)